# White noise that is not strictly stationary

Tags: time-series, stationarity, white-noise

For an exercise I was asked to provide an example of a white noise sequence that is not strictly stationary. I found in multiple sources that an example of this is $$X_t = \sin(2\pi t U) $$ where $t$ a positive integer and $U\sim Uniform[0,1]$.

I could prove that $\mathbb{E}(X_t) = 0$ and $Cov(X_t,X_{t+h}) = 0$ for $h\not=0$ and $Cov(X_t,X_{t+h}) = \frac{1}{2}$ for $h=0$. So it is a white noise sequence.

However, why is this sequence also strictly stationary? I would say that the distribution of $X_t\in[-1,1]$ is the same regardless of $t$, for example $\mathbb{P}\left(X_t>\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4}$ for every $t$. Could someone clarify why this is not a strictly stationary sequence?

Comment: Hint: for a few different values of $h,$ plot the curve $(\sin(2\pi t u), \sin(2\pi(t+h)u))$ as $u$ ranges from $0$ to $1.$